# How to set section headers without repeating data in tableview iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a table view and now I'm initialising the table like,

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [arr count]+1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [arr count]+1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{

    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
    if (row == 0) 
    {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] init];
        return cell;
    }
    else
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"moduleCell";
        MyTableViewCell *cell = (MyTableViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: CellIdentifier];

        if (cell == nil) 
        {

            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

            cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            cell.selectedBackgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@""]];
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

        }
        current = [arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row-1];
        [cell setCellDetails:arr WithIndex:row-1 withParentView:self];
        return cell;
    }
}
```

When I'm doing this data repeating in my tableview. Before I do this, I did,

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}
```

This is working but I need to set section headers like titles. So is there a way to set section headers without repeating data?

Comment: if (cell == nil) {.....}else{ //use the same code here(as in if part).)  }

Comment: can u show us what kind of result you need as image or els. In any case you customise your tableView header using two delegate methods of tableView 'viewForHeaderInSection' and 'titleForHeaderInSection'.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if(indexPath.section == 0){//for first section

    }else if(indexPath.section == 1){//for second section

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement this method:

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (section==0) {
        return "name";
    }else{
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: ok. Then the objects in my array has a date. I need to set headers using this dates like `Today, Yesterday, 28 Feb, Last week etc`. Is it possible?

Comment: That kind of intelligent formatting of dates is a lot harder than you would think and deserves its own question (or doing a google search).

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep heading in Array. So, you can avoid hardcoded in the delegate method.

```
    NSArray *heading=@[@"Today",@"Yesterday",@"Tomorrow"];


    - (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
            NSString *heading = [heading objectAtIndex:section]; //  
            return heading;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

        var cstmView:UIView!

        let lbl:UILabel

        cstmView = UIView()

        cstmView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,tableView.contentSize.width,70.0)

        let logo:UIImageView = UIImageView();

        logo.image = UIImage(named: "logo_with_lightGrayColor")

        logo.frame = CGRectMake(8.0,10.0,200.0,60.0)

        lbl = UILabel()

        lbl.frame = CGRectMake(8.0,80.0,200.0,20.0)

        lbl.text = "USER NAME"

        lbl.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

        lbl.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(15.0)

        cstmView .addSubview(logo)

        cstmView.addSubview(lbl)

        return cstmView;

    }
```

You should implement custom header for `tableview`.